# MKMapView Latitude and Longitude Coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, mkmapview

I'm currently working with the MKMapView and I'm trying to get data to appear on screen. To accomplish this I've decided to right a small MapDataProvider that spits out an array of MKAnnotation objects - each containing a coordinate with random latitude and  longitude values.

I've already made sure that my MKMapView is hooked up to my controller and the array of MKAnnotation objects are coming from my MapDataProvider correctly...but for some reason..when I try and specify coordinates in North America (ex. 48, -84)..nothing appears on the MKMapView.

After playing around I found out that any longitude value less than 0 gives me this issue.

I've tried verifying the coordinate value for each MKAnnotation object in my collection, but CLLocation2DIsValue() keeps returning false.

**Question**:

What range of values can I enter for latitude and longitude for a CLLocationCoordinate2D so my pins show up in North America?

To give a bit more context, here's the method being invoked in the MapDataProvider:

+(NSArray *) getMockMapData{

```
NSMutableArray *tempMapData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15];

for (int i=0; i< 15; i++) {

    double latitude = rand()%20 +50;
    double longitude = -107  + rand()%10;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

    if(CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(coord) == NO)
        continue;

    [tempMapData addObject:[MockMapData 
                            dataForValues:[@"Item " stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] description]]
                                 subTitle:[@"Item " stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]description]] 
                                coordinate:coord]];
    }
    return tempMapData;
}
```

Comment: Latitude can be from -90 to 90 and longitude can be from -180 to 180 so 48,-84 is valid.  Can you post the code that adds the annotations?

Comment: Thanks for your response. After playing around with it some more, i switched out arcrandom for rand and that change correct my issue.

Comment: Updated the source with latest fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code was this:

```
double latitude = arcrandom()%20 +50;
double longitude = -107  + arcrandom()%10;
```

(Actually, you probably had `arc4random`, not `arcrandom`.)

The `arc4random` function returns an unsigned integer value.

Subtracting an integer (`-107`) from that value resulted in an overflow which gave values like `4294967189`.  That would definitely be an invalid longitude.

Instead of switching to `rand` (which the documentation says is a "bad random number generator"), use `arc4random` (which I believe is preferred) and force a floating point calculation by writing `-107.0` instead of `-107`:

```
double latitude = arc4random()%20 +50;
double longitude = -107.0  + arc4random()%10;
```

An unrelated point is that if `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid` says `NO`, you are just doing a `return` without sending back any value (which you need to according to the method declaration).  Either do `return tempMapData;` or `continue;`.

Comment: Thorough answer. Thanks for explaining the differences between the random number generators I came across.

In regards to the random 'return' statement, you're absolutely right. I normally don't do that, but for the purposes of giving everyone a bit more context (and simply getting something up and running) I thought I'd make the exception.

Answer (score 0):

[Canappi](http://www.canappi.com) is based on a simple programming language, mdsl, that is used to generate Objective-C code for iOS. They have a map control that allows you to achieve what you need from a simple descriptor. As this example shows, you can use static push pin locations, or dynamic ones:

```
map venuMap (32,610,708,360) {
    Standard ;
    show user ;
    area .1,.1; 
    //location 30.275806,-97.740128 ('TX Capital' , '1200 N Congress');
    locationReference lat, long (sDetTitle, address);
}
```

The generated code is open, so you can just copy and paste it back into your app.